# Road conditions for Guwahati to Tawang in November

Tags: india, road-trips, winter, bhutan

I am planning to travel to Tawang via Guwahati in November by road [by taking a cab].

But while googling I found conflicting info on road conditions in November, and some are advising against going there in winter.

Can anyone advise on road conditions in November between Guwahati and Tawang?

Answer (score 1):

Road conditions are manageable. You can visit Tawang during November like we have done. But remember that it will be very cold specially near Sella Pass with chances of Snowfall.

So just be prepared for that and enjoy your vacation. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I plan to get a cab to go to Tawang, is it readily available from Guwahati or i should book a tour in advance.